# Do presentations need margins?

Tags: beamer, margins

When showing a presentation, slides are typically shown by projecting the contents onto a white projection screen.  Seeing that the aim of margins is to have white around a block of text, margins are already “for free” when projecting in this way.

With that in mind, is there any harm in setting

`\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm}`
and
`\setbeamersize{text margin right=0mm}`?

Comment: I think that one reason could be that sometimes the projection might fill the whole screen and then there are no "free" margins.

Comment: @user93559 I've also seen the projection being off the screen... that is rather a matter of aligning the projector?

Comment: I think you are right but I have also seen conferences where the presentations where shown on a huge tv screen, I think in this case the "free margins" were only the black frame of the screen.

Comment: @gerrit Margins are used to 'control' your eyes in order to follow a certain direction. A newspaper has margin, a worksheet has margins, a book has margins. A piece of paper (or a presentation) using any Bohr hydrogen atom radius of free space to overprint with something 'important' just looks awful

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Some maps have no margins or locally no margins.  When I draw on the whiteboard I don't use margins.  My computer screen does not have margins.  I think.

Comment: If you are not 100% about the location yours slides are going to be presented I would not risk the no-margins solution. Often projectors are badly aligned, parts of the presentation are off-screen, etc.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: The margin is not 'white space' but 'empty canvas' so should match the background colour. If the book has pink pages, the margins should typically be pink. You'd at least want *a* pink margin around the text. The same for a TikZ node or a coloured box. You don't want the text right at the edge. So if your slides use white background (with no header footer text or lines to left or right), then you might count the white screen as margin. Except this won't work as there is a visible difference between lit/projected white on screen and the white of the background screen.

Comment: @cfr True.  I was assuming white paper/canvas.

Comment: That's often a false assumption for Beamer, though. It is true by default, I know, but most people seem to use a coloured background and/or coloured bars or rules to mark the header and/or footer etc.